# AuthorizeNet CIM refund Transactions for recurring profile

Tags: php, authentication, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, authorize.net

I have created a recurring profile for a customer.Customer gets the subscription by pay from credit card functionality of Authorize.net CIM module.After paid the first Subscription by Customer ,I want to refund some amount from paid amount of first transaction to customer.Can some one help me .I have searched a lot on google but could not get the refund api sample code of authorize.net CIM.

Please Help.Any Help will be Appreciated and will save my time.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the format of the XML request and response for Refund a Transaction for a Customer Profile at http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/#charge-customer-profiles-refunding-a-transaction-for-a-customer-profile.  You can even run a test transaction in the console using your sandbox API Login and Transaction Key.